# Apex chart text-truncate customize

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

I am working on the Apex chart. When there is a long text item in `categories` array, the apex chart don't show the whole text But it shows some part of it by doing text-eclipse and showing it with three-dot like this: `Department of Environmenta...`.

Can we customize it showing the whole text? It would be nice if the text would go to the next line `below the first line` if it does not fit in the same row.

Here is the code

```
import React from "react";
import ReactApexChart from "react-apexcharts";

class ApexChart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      series: [
        {
          name: "Progress",
          data: [64, 55, 21, 18, 76, 41, 44, 14, 66, 32]
        },
        {
          name: "Expenses (In thousound)",
          data: [53, 32, 42, 22, 29, 80, 16, 49, 78, 11]
        }
      ],

      options: {
        colors: ["#519ca5", "#2274A5"],
        plotOptions: {
          bar: {
            horizontal: true,
            dataLabels: {
              position: "top"
            }
          }
        },
        chart: {
          toolbar: {
            show: false,
          }
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          offsetX: 0,
          style: {
            fontSize: "12px",
            colors: ["#fff"]
          }
        },
        stroke: {
          show: true,
          width: 1,
          colors: ["#fff"]
        },
        xaxis: {
          //   type: "datetime",
          categories: [
            "Department of Psychology",
            "Department of Natural Science",
            "Department of Environmental Science",
            "Department of Literature And Finance",
            "Department of Foreign Employement",
            "Department of Transport Management",
            "Department of culture media and sport",

          ]
        },
        legend: {
          position: "right",
          markers: {
            width: 24,
            height: 24,
            strokeWidth: 0,
            strokeColor: "#fff",
            fillColors: undefined,
            radius: 2,
            customHTML: undefined,
            onClick: undefined,
            offsetX: 0,
            offsetY: 0
          }
        }
      }
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://my-json-server.typicode.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/yearly")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => console.log(res));
    this.setState({
      options: { ...this.state.options }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="chart">
        <ReactApexChart
          height="100%"
          options={this.state.options}
          series={this.state.series}
          type="bar"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ApexChart;
```

And here is the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-johnson-ty2dd)

Answer (score 2):

If you have long labels, you should provide the categories in a nested array format. Each item in the array becomes a new line.

```js
xaxis: {
  categories: [
    ["Department", "of Psychology"],
    ["Department", "of Natural Science"],
    ["Department", "of Environmental Science"],
    ["Department", "of Literature And Finance"],
    ["Department", "of Foreign Employement"],
    ["Department", "of Transport Management"],
    ["Department", "of culture media"]
  ]
}
```

Here's the resulting y-axis
[image]

Updated [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-mendeleev-b71kx) example

Docs for multiline labels - https://apexcharts.com/docs/multiline-text-and-line-breaks-in-axes-labels/

Comment: categories array is static for now. But while implementation, the array is going to be the data that comes from API. what should I do in that case? I can not count the word and split them like [ if the string is more than 80 characters ] because of splitting in the word. I guess, We can suppose that this array is coming from API.

Comment: If the string is coming from API, you should check if each category contains multiple words. You can easily split them and create an array on the client-side.

Comment: when the string get truncated? I am not understanding when it is! Sometimes it truncates when the text length is 26 sometimes 27.